# Reshape dataframe so observations in one column are column names and the corresponding column is the value in it

Tags: r, reshape2

```
 X.nm.   X.A.        variable
<dbl>  <dbl>           <chr>
  300 3.9472 100ng _1_36.712
  350 0.2060 100ng _1_36.712
  380 0.1118 100ng _1_36.712
  400 0.0607 100ng _1_36.712
  450 0.0210 100ng _1_36.712
  500 0.0129 100ng _1_36.712
  300 0.0099 100ng _2_36.712
  750 0.0099 100ng _2_36.712
  350 0.4060 100ng _2_36.712
  300 0.4060 100ng _1_45.712
  350 0.6118 100ng _1_45.712
  400 0.9607 100ng _1_45.712
```

I have the dataframe above and I'd like to reshape it so that X.nm. is a column, the observations in variable becomes the column name and X.A. are the observations in that column. How do I do this? Then how can I make that solution a function because I'd like to do this to multiple dataframes and export them as excel files.

I tried doing dcast and spread but the issue is if X.nm. and X.A. become the variable where the other 3 (Reaction.Type_Trial_Actual.Total.Seconds) in the variable column are left as their own column, I get issues with duplicate identifiers. The original dataset has the columns: X.nm., X.A. , Reaction.Type, Trial, Actual.Total.Seconds. I've already tried this code and it doesn't work:

```
mc5<- orig.df %>% unite(variable,c(Reaction.Type, Trial, Actual.Total.Seconds)) 
mc6<- dcast(mc5, X.nm.~X.A.+variable, value.var = mc5$X.A.)
```

Sample of Desired:

```
 X.nm.   100ng _1_36.712    100ng _2_36.712    100ng _1_45.712
  300         3.9472        0.0099                0.4060
  350         0.2060        0.4060                0.6118
```

etc.

Comment: `dcast(mc5, X.nm. ~ variable, value.var = "X.A.")`

Answer (score 0):

The answer using the `tidyr` package is:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(orig.df, key = variable, value = X.A.)
```

Try that if nobody gives you the correct `reshape2` way of doing it.